# Position sprite at center of screen

Tags: xna, windows-phone-7

I am trying to get a sprite to position itself at the center of the screen but nothing seems to be working for me.
I'm trying

```
Viewport viewport = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport;
logoPosition = new Vector2((viewport.Width - towerImage.Width) / 2,
                           (viewport.Height - towerImage.Height) / 2);
```

and

```
spriteBatch.Draw(towerImage, centre, null, Color.White, 0, baseOrigin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

This is my first time using XNA and I don't really have a clue what I'm doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you pasted your example wrong, you're not even using the `logoPosition` you calculated when drawing, and you're not showing what the contents of `centre`and `baseOrigin`are, so it's hard to tell you where the problem is.

But anyway I'd use the `position` and `origin` parameters of `SpriteBatch.Draw` in order to draw the image centered. In two steps, although you could inline:

1. Calculate the center of the screen and the center of the image:

   ```
   Vector2 screenCenter = new Vector2(viewport.Width / 2f, viewport.Height / 2f);
   Vector2 imageCenter = new Vector2(towerImage.Width / 2f, towerImage.Height / 2f);
   ```
2. Use the center of the screen as the `position` and the center of the image as the `origin`:

   ```
                                // position                          // origin
   spriteBatch.Draw(towerImage, screenCenter, null, Color.White, 0f, imageCenter, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used XNA for a windows phone but I already can tell what your problem is.  You aren't following order of operations.  Try this:

```
Viewport viewport = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport;
logoPosition = new Vector2(viewport.Width - towerImage.Width / 2,
                           viewport.Height - towerImage.Height / 2);
```

You must divide the second height/width before you subtract if from the original.  Otherwise it just negates itself and then divides 0 by 2.

Comment: You must have misunderstood some part, since what he was doing is essentially the same as `viewportSize/2 - imageSize/2` which is correct. In other words, it calculates the center of the screen, and then subtracts half of the size of the image in order to center it there. Also, the thing about the negation would only happen if viewport and towerImage had the same size, which is unlikely, and even in that case, the result is correct (i.e. 0/2 = 0).